# Get Index by X and Y

Tags: c#, math

There's a way to get X and Y based on Index like

```
x = index % columns;
y = index / columns;
```

How can I reverse this and get Index based on X and Y?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming we're dealing with integers here, if you have the following code:

```
x = index % columns; // get the remainder of dividing index by columns 
y = index / columns; // get the result of dividing index by columnsn
```

Then the reverse would be:

```
index = y * columns + x;
```